# Windows Azure no subscription on laptop but able to logon using desktop

Tags: azure

It's not really a programming question, but I'm at a loss now.
I'm a co-administrator for my employer for a virtual machine and using a desktop (my desktop) -- where I initially added the VM -- I can login to https://manage.windowsazure.com/ but when I try to login (using the same account) on my laptop I get a "no subscriptions found" error page.
It's the same account - as far as I can tell at least.

I've tried clearing *all* history for all browsers and the same result. I've tried different browsers, same result. I've tried to clear all history again - same result.
I've tried contacting MS - but they have no dedicated support for these matters, so eventually I was redirected to the Azure forums and StackOverflow.

Comment: Just speculating but could it be because of Microsoft Account / Azure Active Directory Account? On one machine you're logging in using your Microsoft Account and on other using Azure AD Account (Work or school account)?

Comment: if all fails also try to refresh and force , or run it in a private sessio.. MS Accounts can get quirky , especially when running on Windows 8 with synced accounts :-)

Comment: Have you tried using InPrivate or Incognito mode?

Comment: both of the options (combined) did the trick. Incognito and sign in with MS account, not AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers from @gaurav-mantri and @techmike2kx combined did the trick; 
Into private (incognito) mode logging on to the Azure Management site I could login using my Microsoft account - not using the "work or school" account I normally use for Office365.

Comment: Thanks--this helped me out.  It's nutty that they make you chose between personal and business accounts in the first place. . .